# Html img tag does not show image in browser

Tags: html

Taking a shot at html and I can't get an image to show. I have the image in the same folder as the html document. I have also checked the file name and extension, but am still coming up empty. Here is a screen shot of the text editor the folder and the browser. [html image issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2Wda.png)

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: You are the victim of unicode quotes. Use a real code editor to avoid them.

Comment: what code editor would you suggest?

Comment: Atom is nice, Text Mate 2 and Text Wrangler are simple. Any code editor would really be an improvement.

Comment: downloaded Atom and just retyped the quotes. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Can't use spaces in src paths.

`<img src="kobe%20bryant.jpg">`

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I made was using TextEdit. This is not a true code editor. It reads quotation marks differently than html requires. I downloaded Atom, which took like 1 minute and retyped the quotation marks in there. It worked.